# MITライセンスでの配布

Tags: python, ライセンス, mit-license

Pythonで作ったアプリケーションをMITライセンスで公開しようと思います。
Pythonプログラムで使っているパッケージには以下のライセンスになっているものが含まれています。
・BSDライセンス
・Apache Software License
・MITライセンス
MITライセンス以外のパッケージも含まれていますが、MITライセンスで公開できるのでしょうか。
また、ライセンスを表記する際はパッケージ名とライセンス名以外の記述で何が必要になるでしょうか。パッケージの作者名も必要でしょうか。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- もしかして：`import`文などでモジュールを読み込む場合で、そのモジュールがあなたのアプリケーションに付属していない場合は、そのモジュールのライセンスはあなたのアプリケーションに影響を与えません。
- 3つのライセンスを共存させる場合
  互換性はありますが、100%とはいえません。

  > In general, lax permissive licenses (modified BSD, X11, Expat, Apache, Python, etc.) are compatible with each other. [出典](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/license-compatibility.html)
- ライセンス表記
  MITライセンスを表記するときは、[規定のライセンス文](https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT)を使用しないといけません。もしMITライセンスで公開された既存のモジュールなどを使用する場合は、そのモジュールのライセンス文そのものが著作権表示になります。

間違っていた場合はごめんなさい。

Comment: import文などでモジュールを読み込む場合で、そのモジュールがあなたのアプリケーションに付属していない場合は、そのモジュールのライセンスはあなたのアプリケーションに影響を与えません。というのは自分が作成したpythonアプリでimportしたパッケージすべてが対象になるとは限らないということでしょうか。

Comment: MITライセンスで公開された既存のモジュールなどを使用する場合は、そのモジュールのライセンス文そのものが著作権表示になります。のところのこの既存モジュールのライセンス文はどうやって手に入れたらよいでしょうか。

Comment: 1. あなたのアプリの中で、importしたものが「アプリの外部」(=利用者がpipとかで別途インストールする必要があるところ)にある場合、あなたのアプリは「参照読み込み」をしているだけなので、あなたのアプリはimportしたもののライセンスに影響されません。

Comment: 2. そのモジュールがアプリに付属している場合は、ライセンス文はモジュールが存在しているところの近くに「COPYING」「LICENSE」などというファイル名で存在しているか、そのモジュール・ファイルの冒頭にあるかのどちらかです。

Comment: １．つまり、pip freezeコマンドで出力されている一覧にあるパッケージをインポートしてもそのパッケージのライセンス表記は不要になるということでしょうか。